# elasticsearch 6 ESIntegTestCase "codebase property already set"

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm attempting an upgrade to ES 6.2 from 2.3.4.

Previously, we'd integration-tested code by using NodeBuilder and running up a local ES node. I'd rather swap this out for the ESIntegTestCase usage if possible.

However, when I try to run an integration test I get the following error:

`at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:190)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:592)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: codebase property already set: codebase.metrics-core -> file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.0/metrics-core-3.1.0.jar, cannot set to file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.readPolicy(Security.java:236)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:139)
    ... 4 more`

What does this mean, and how I can I fix it?

My test class is annotated with: `@RunWith(com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class)` and extends `ESIntegTestCase` if that helps at all.

Thank you for any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21544 ESIntegTestCase should also no longer really be used unless you're testing a plugin or something like that (see reply posting here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-deal-with-this-particular-jar-hell-issue/135662/4).

See here for more: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/codebase-property-already-set-when-running-esintegtestcase/135659/2

The best best methodology for integration testing with elasticsearch that I have found now is mentioned in that discuss posting: use testcontainers-elasticsearch (https://github.com/dadoonet/testcontainers-java-module-elasticsearch)

You need docker installed on the machine running the tests, but it will automatically pull the required docker image, start up the container and tear it down again at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If developing a plugin so still needing embedded ES, then perhaps setting system property `-Dtests.gradle=false` can work around the issue.

since BootstrapForTesting.java L175 contains:

```
if (System.getProperty("tests.gradle") == null) {
  addClassCodebase(codebases, "plugin-classloader", "org.elasticsearch.plugins.ExtendedPluginsClassLoader");
  addClassCodebase(codebases, "elasticsearch-secure-sm", "org.elasticsearch.secure_sm.SecureSM");
}
```